# Make 7 colums using bootstrap and customize them (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have 7 columns(monday-sunday) using bootstrap.

Here is code in View

```
<div id="left3" style="padding-right: 140px;" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">Mon</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">Tue</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">Wen</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">Thu</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">Fri</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">Sat</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">Sun</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">3</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">4</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">5</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">6</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">7</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

And when I try to add border like this

`style="border-style: solid; border-color: #1d69b4;border-radius: 10px;"`

I got this

[image]

How I can center text in column and make it like on this design?

[image]

Comment: find [this bootply](https://www.bootply.com/XO9zlQNHbE)

Comment: Thank's. It helps me@Curiousdev

Comment: Think you would have to have all your [rows in your column](https://www.bootply.com/xagIisusUl) and then use js to equalise the height between "rows"

Comment: @SukhomlinEugene that's great :)